# Candlestick-Chart without date on x-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, candlestick-chart

I wanna use the Candlestick-Chart  from amcharts without the datetime on the x-axis.

I wanna use numbers instead of the date.

Example:
http://www.amcharts.com/demos/candlestick-chart/

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use date-based category axis for the Candlestick chart. For that simply remove the [`"parseDates": true`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#parseDates) from your `categoryAxis` config.

Once that is done, the chart will not think of the category axis as a date scale and you will be able to use any string or number as a category.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "graphs": [ {
    "id": "g1",
    "closeField": "close",
    "fillColors": "#7f8da9",
    "highField": "high",
    "lineColor": "#7f8da9",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lowField": "low",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "negativeFillColors": "#db4c3c",
    "negativeLineColor": "#db4c3c",
    "openField": "open",
    "title": "Price:",
    "type": "candlestick",
    "valueField": "close"
  } ],
  "chartScrollbar": {
    "graph": "g1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "scrollbarHeight": 30
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true
  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "date": "1",
    "open": "136.65",
    "high": "136.96",
    "low": "134.15",
    "close": "136.49"
  }, {
    "date": "2",
    "open": "135.26",
    "high": "135.95",
    "low": "131.50",
    "close": "131.85"
  }, {
    "date": "3",
    "open": "132.90",
    "high": "135.27",
    "low": "128.30",
    "close": "135.25"
  }, {
    "date": "4",
    "open": "134.94",
    "high": "137.24",
    "low": "132.63",
    "close": "135.03"
  }, {
    "date": "5",
    "open": "136.76",
    "high": "136.86",
    "low": "132.00",
    "close": "134.01"
  }, {
    "date": "6",
    "open": "131.11",
    "high": "133.00",
    "low": "125.09",
    "close": "126.39"
  }, {
    "date": "7",
    "open": "123.12",
    "high": "127.75",
    "low": "120.30",
    "close": "125.00"
  }, {
    "date": "8",
    "open": "128.32",
    "high": "129.35",
    "low": "126.50",
    "close": "127.79"
  }, {
    "date": "9",
    "open": "128.29",
    "high": "128.30",
    "low": "123.71",
    "close": "124.03"
  }, {
    "date": "10",
    "open": "122.74",
    "high": "124.86",
    "low": "119.65",
    "close": "119.90"
  } ]
} );
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```